# Calculation of density metric of 0.75 height quantile based on Airborne LiDAR Scanning point cloud data by lidR package

Tags: r, lidr, grid-metrics

This is a piece of code that I wrote:

```
metrics<-function(z){Q75=quantile(z,probs=c(0.75))         

aboveq75=sum(z>Q75)

dh75=aboveq75/length(z)

return(dh75)}

DH75<-grid_metrics(lid,~metrics(Z),res = 30)
```

I want to calculate the proportion of point cloud quantity above 0.75 height quantile in the total point cloud quantity based on 30-meter grid scale. This metrics can be used to participate in the construction of a forest inventory attributes prediction model using an area-based approach.Because it reflects the distribution of branches and leaves in the upper and middle canopy.But the number of points above the 0.75 quantile is by definition always going be approximately 0.25.Is my definition wrong? or you have a better idea about the Calculation of density metric of 0.75 height quantile.

The result of my definition:
[image]

The corresponding value of the grid:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "But why does the result look less different per pixel?" mean? Less different than what? What has that got to do with your question about counting points above a quantile? Can you point (no pun intended) us to a sample data set so we can all work on the same data? . And how are you plotting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of points above the 0.75 quantile is *by definition* always going be approximately 0.25. The variation you are getting is because if there's only a small number of points then the quantile computation is approximate or there's tied values. Compare:

```
> metrics(runif(1000))
[1] 0.25
> metrics(runif(12))
[1] 0.25
> metrics(runif(13))
[1] 0.2307692
```

The value for `metrics(12)` is exactly 0.25 because 3 are greater than it and 9 are less than or equal to it, and 3/12 is 0.25 - but with 13 values you've got 3 greater than it and 10 less then or equal, producing the value 3/13 = 0.2307692 as seen.

If instead you want the number of points in each grid square with Z values greater than the 0.75 quantile over **all the points in the cloud**, compute your threshold outside the function from all the Z values. Here's a reproducible example using sample data from the `lidR` package:

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
Q75=quantile(las$Z,0.75)
Q75
##   75% 
## 19.32
```

Then use your `metrics` function minus that one line:

```
metrics <- 
  function(z){
   aboveq75=sum(z>Q75)
   dh75=aboveq75/length(z)
   return(dh75)
  }
```

Then run as before - I'm using a 3m grid here because the data is different:

```
> DH75<-grid_metrics(las,~metrics(Z),res = 3)
> plot(DH75)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you，I want to calculate the ratio of the number of points above a given height quantile to the total number of point clouds based on  30-meter grid scale.

Comment: You've only got one point cloud.

Comment: @zxforestry see edit for map of point count above 0.75 *global* quartile threshold (or any threshold you want to compute)

Comment: thank you for your clear answer,happy,enjoying.Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

It was difficult to understand exactly what you were asking, but I think this solution using ggplot2 to view the rasters will better suit your needs.

I could only test using my own sample data, but hopefully this will translate to your data as well.

```
#dependencies
library(lidR)
library(ggplot2)
library(stats)

#specify file path
infile <- 'path_to_your_cloud.las'

#read in las cloud
las <- readLAS(infile)

#create density raster
density_plot <- grid_density(las, res = 10)

#calculate 75th percentile point density
Q75 = quantile(density_plot$point_density, probs = 0.75)

#filter raster based on value
density_plot_Q75 <- density_plot[density_plot$point_density > Q75]

#plot unfiltered raster
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = density_plot , aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = point_density)) + 
  coord_quickmap()

#plot filtered raster
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = density_plot_Q75 , aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = point_density)) + 
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image: Unfiltered Raster]
[image: Filtered Raster]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry, I didn't describe it clearly in the question.         I want to calculate the percentage of point clouds above the 75% height quantile as a percentage of the total point clouds.However, the difference between the values of each 30-meter grid calculated using my method is small.What's wrong with my method?   Thank you again.

Comment: I used your code to visualize the grid,  when using ggplot ，The program reported an error“ Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class RasterLayer ”，What's the problem？ Thank you  for your help.